# Как вывести значения из терминала с помощью python?

Tags: python

Я новичок в Python(вообще в программирование) так, что прошу прощение за глупый вопрос! Хочу запустить elf-файл, который просит ввести key: и text:.Программа запускается через терминал в Linux, но вводить эти поля нужно вручную. Как сделать чтобы эти поля считывались и потом уже работать с ними? Пытаюсь сделать, что то типо brute force:

```
import os 
command = "./bcry"
answ = os.system(command)
```

Comment: `sys.argv`?????

Comment: если использовать, то что я написал можно делать `python3.6 brute.py test` `sys.argv[0]` вернет путь к файлу, а `sys.arg[1]` передаст test

Answer (score 0):

Вообще это можно делать [по-разному](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output), но я предпочитаю такой вариант:

```
import os
command = "./bcry"
answ = os.popen(command).read()
```

Это то, что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Даа, но после этого все равно требуется вводить значение в терминал.

Comment: @Fomin567 `print(answ)`?

Comment: Я хотел использовать модуль pwn, но появляется ошибка. 
p = process("./bcry")
p.sendafter("key:", key +"\n")
p.sendafter("text:", test_flag +"\n")

Comment: @Fomin567 Это такая ошибка?

Comment: Это код, который пытался запустить

Comment: @Fomin567 А ошибка где?

Comment: Ошибка вот: [+] Starting program './bcry': Done
[ERROR] Neither 'qemu-i386' nor 'qemu-i386-static' are available
[*] Program './bcry' stopped with exit code 0

Comment: @Fomin567 Тогда задайте пожалуйста отдельный вопрос, я уже вообще перестал понимать о чем речь...